# Is it possible to "transfer" a session between selenium.webdriver and requests.session

Tags: python, session, selenium, browser, python-requests

In theory, if I copy all of the cookies from selenium's `webdriver` object to `requests.Session` object, would requests be able to continue on as if the session was not interrupted?

Specifically, I am interested in writing automation where I get to specific location on the webpage via selenium, then pass on a certain download link to `requests`, which would download and verify specific bytes out of the file, and sometimes a full file. (The value of the file downloaded would change based on my interaction in selenium)

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Yes it will definitely work. Following code snippet should help as well -

```
headers = {
"User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
}
s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)

for cookie in driver.get_cookies():
    c = {cookie['name']: cookie['value']}
    s.cookies.update(c)
```

Comment: Great, thanks. What is the purpose of updating headers in line #2, and where does the parameter 'headers' come from?

Comment: Just update my answer. Headers is just for sending any extra headers, most of the sites expect a user-agent string of popular browsers.

Comment: Maybe it would be more pythonic to substitute the last three lines for: `s.cookies.update( {c['name']:c['value'] for c in driver.get_cookies()} )`

Comment: Will It work the other way around, can you start a selenium browser with the request session?

Comment: @EndermanAPM, Yes it will. But there is a limitation with Selenium Webdriver that you can add cookies only for current domain. So your code should have the following flow - Open Webpage using selenium, Add cookies using Webdriver, Open the Webpage again, and it will work.

Comment: would it be possible to do other way around? Say I have active session with request.session(), can I pass it onto selenium? @VikasOjha

Comment: @BurakhanAksoy, please check my above comment. Let me know if that doesnt help.

Comment: @VikasOjha bummer :( I am trying to connect to linkedin. using selenium first and login triggers a captcha-like security step. When I solve captcha it logs in successfully. Any thoughts? But If I login with request.sessions() first, then I get error when I implement driver.add_cookies(cookies). It gives the following error -> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid argument: missing 'name'