# Using Python to request draftkings.com info that requires login?

Tags: python, authentication, web, python-requests, screen-scraping

I'm trying to get contest data from the url: "https://www.draftkings.com/contest/gamecenter/32947401"

If you go to this URL and aren't logged in, it'll just re-direct you to the lobby.  If you're logged in, it'll actually show you the contest results.

**Here's some things I tried:**

-First, I used Chrome's Dev networking tools to watch requests while I manually logged in

-I then tried copying the cookie that I thought contained the authentication info, it was of the form:

```
 'ajs_anonymous_id=%123123123123123, mlc=true; optimizelyEndUserId'
```

-I then stored that cookie as an Evironment variable and ran this code:

```
HEADERS= {'cookie': os.environ['MY_COOKIE'] }
requests.get(draft_kings_url, headers= HEADERS)
```

No luck, this just gave me the lobby.

I then tried request's built in:

- HTTPBasicAuth
- HTTPDigestAuth

No luck here either.

I'm no python expert by far, and I've pretty much exhausted what I know and the search results I've found.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

The tool that you want is selenium. Something along the lines of:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get(r"https://www.draftkings.com/contest/gamecenter/32947401" )

username = browser.find_element_by_id("user")
username.send_keys("username")

password = browser.find_element_by_id("password")
password.send_keys("top_secret")

login = selenium.find_element_by_name("login")
login.click()
```

Comment: hey Batman. I used your answer with some modification and it seems to work!

Once I'm logged in, is there any way to switch back to using requests? Or do I have to keep doing all work through the webdriver?

Comment: You absolutely can switch between the two. You just need to transfer the cookies from the webdriver to your requests session. Look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639014/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-session-between-selenium-webdriver-and-requests-s)

Comment: You can log in to draft kings with requests. Selenium is overkill.

Answer (score 0):

Use fiddler to see the exact request they are making when you try to log in. Then use Session class in requests package.

```
import requests
session = requests.Session()
session.get('YOUR_URL_LOGIN_PAGE')
```

this will save all the cookies from your url in your session variable (Like when you use a browser).
Then make a post request to the login url with appropriate data.

You dont have to manually pass cookie data as it is auto generated when you first visit a website. However you can set some header explicitly like `UserAgent` etc by:

```
session.headers.update({'header_name':'header_value'})
```

HTTPBasicAuth & HTTPDigestAuth might not work based on the website.