# Download an Image Using Selenium Webdriver in Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to download an image from a URL using Selenium Webdriver in Python. The site is protected by a login page, so can't just save the URL contents using requests. I am able to get text from the site after logging in, but I can't figure out how to save an image.

After I log in to the site, I can do `browser.save_screenshot(filename + '.png')` but that image is not the correct size as the original.

The code that I have now is this:

```
browser = webdriver.Chrome('../chromedriver')
browser.get('www.example.com/login')
# send username and password, click submit

browser.get('www.example.com/123')
html = browser.page_source
printData(html)

# this url is an image file
browser.get('www.example.com/get_photo.php?id=123')
browser.save_screenshot(filename + '.png')
```

Ideally I would like to replace the `save_screenshot()` with something like

```
with open(filename + '.jpeg', 'w') as img:
    img.write(browser.download_current_image())
```

or even something like this, interacting with the popup menu

```
browser.right_click()
browser.down_arrow_key()
browser.return_key()
```

or simulating a keypress

```
browser.command_key()
browser.s_key()
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6813704/how-to-download-an-image-using-selenium-any-version) question gives the answers that I want, but not for Python. If there is a way to do any of the things suggested in that question (besides taking a screenshot) in Python, that would be a great solution.

Comment: *site is protected by a login page, so can't just save the URL contents using requests*... Why do you think that `requests` doesn't support [Authentication](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/)?

Comment: I had this situation before, what I did I'll just copy the webdriver session to requests, then download the image with it.

How to transfer it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639014/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-session-between-selenium-webdriver-and-requests-s

Of course, it depends how secure/complex the website that you're dealing with

Comment: @AldoSuwandi that link was exactly what I was looking for. Thanks! I'll post the code I used as my answer.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here is what I used to download an image from a URL behind a login page by logging in using Selenium Webdriver and then passing the cookies to requests to save the image:

```
headers = {
"User-Agent":
    "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.3; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/44.0.2403.157 Safari/537.36"
}
s = requests.session()
s.headers.update(headers)

for cookie in browser.get_cookies():
    c = {cookie['name']: cookie['value']}
    s.cookies.update(c)

r = s.get(imgurl, allow_redirects=True)
open(filename + '.jpeg', 'wb').write(r.content)
```

Thanks to [AldoSuwandi](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2335360/aldo-suwandi) for showing me how to do this in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32639014/is-it-possible-to-transfer-a-session-between-selenium-webdriver-and-requests-s) post. I also used [this](https://www.codementor.io/aviaryan/downloading-files-from-urls-in-python-77q3bs0un) site to help me figure out how to download an image using requests.

Comment: thanks this worked well and you don't even need selenium